# Loop inside the `focusLost event` does not work

Tags: java, focuslistener

I am learning Java in a YouTube course and I found this problem apparently. I tried to create a loop inside the `focusLost` event. However, it does not work properly (the program ignores it). If anyone has the solution I will be happy to hear it.

```
package Ventanas;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    public  MainFrame() {
        setTitle("Primer JText en Java");
        setBounds(500,500,700,700);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
        add(mainPanel);
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MainPanel extends JPanel{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        setLayout(null);

        Square1 = new JTextField();
        Square2 = new JTextField();

        Square1.setBounds(120, 120 , 100, 25);
        Square2.setBounds(120, 160, 100, 25);

        add(Square1);
        add(Square2);

        focusEvent fEvent = new focusEvent();

        Square1.addFocusListener(fEvent);

    }

     class focusEvent implements FocusListener{


        public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String mail = Square2.getText();

            boolean comprobacion = false;

            for (int i=0; i<mail.length();i++) {

                if (mail.charAt(i)=='@') {

                    comprobacion= true;
                }
            }


            if (comprobacion){
                System.out.println("El email es válido");
            }

            else{
                System.out.println("El email no es válido");

            }

        }       

     }

     JTextField Square1;
     JTextField Square2;


}
public class WindowFocusListenerAndJText {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainFrame();
    }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where's your code?

Comment: Could you please show your code loop inside `focusLost` event? It will be helpful for us to help you :)